# Evaluating lambda calculus: if false false true

Tags: lambda, scheme, semantics, lambda-calculus

> The lambda calculus has the following expressions:
>
> ```
> e ::=           Expressions
>       x         Variables
>       (λx.e)    Functions
>       e e       Function application
> ```
>
> From this base, we can define a number of additional constructs, such as Booleans and conditional statements:
>
> ```
> let true = (λx.(λy.x))
> false = (λx.(λy.y))
> if = (λcond.(λthen.(λelse.cond then else)))
> ```
>
> Showing your work, show the evaluation of the following program:
> `if false false true`.

Maybe `if(false (then false ( else true then true)))`?

But that would just mean exactly what it means. `if false then false else true then true`.

I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Its a practice exam my teacher gave us, he didn't go over how to do this and the only time we did something similar to this was writing a parser in scheme. I'm worried this is going to be on the test and I want to learn how to solve it. Can't really put effort into it if I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Maybe if(false (then false ( else true then true))) But that would just mean exactly what it means.
`if false 
    then false 
else true
    then true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the definitions

```hs
true = (λx.(λy.x))
false = (λx.(λy.y))
if = (λcond.(λthen.(λelse.cond then else)))
```

defined, means that

```hs
true x y = x
false x y = y
if cond then else = cond then else
```

Thus, e.g.,

```hs
   if true true false
-- if cond then else   = cond then else
                       = true true false
                     --  true x    y      = x
                                          = true
```

There's no more definitions to apply here, so we have our result.

Now you can try working out your example.

Comment: Thank you for your simple explanation it helped how you defined it in terms of x and y. Heres my example worked out.

` if false false true
-- if cond then else   = cond then else
                                = false false true
                              --  false  y  x   =  false x y =  y
                                                                       = false`

Comment: you're welcome. :) I just wrote down what it meant when you apply those definitions. this is also known as "combinatory logic", where we just write down the `=` definitions. it is equivalent to the lambda expressions. check it out! (it's on Wikipedia, too). the other way to go is apply them one argument at a time, as the other answer is showing.

Answer (score 1):

"if", "true", and "false" are not language keywords with a meaning, they are just (meta-language) names of functions.
Similarly, "cond", "then" and "else" are function parameters; the words don't mean anything.

I think this is actually easier to follow if you use nonsense identifiers (this is purely a symbol-manipulation exercise).

Define the meaningless

```
a = (λx.(λy.x))
b = (λx.(λy.y))
c = (λx.(λy.(λz.x y z)))
```

and evaluate

```
   c b b a
—> (λx.(λy.(λz.x y z))) b b a
—> (λy.(λz.b y z)) b a
—> (λz.b b z) a
—> b b a
—> (λx.(λy.y)) b a
—> ...
```

and you will eventually end up with `(λx.(λy.x))`, which is the definition of "a" ("true").

Comment: Thank you for your help this is a bit confusing for me to follow especially since I have to show my work on the test, but I appreciate you trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
   if false false true
   {substituting name for definition}
-> (λcond.(λthen.(λelse.cond then else))) false false true
   {beta reduction}
-> (λthen.(λelse.false then else)) false true
   {beta reduction}
-> (λelse.false false else) true
   {beta reduction}
-> false false true
   {substituting name for definition}
-> (λx.(λy.y)) false true
   {beta reduction}
-> (λy.y) true
   {beta reduction}
-> true
   {substituting name for definition}
-> (λx.(λy.x))
```

You can run it yourself using the interactive interpreter on [this
page](https://www.easycalculation.com/analytical/lambda-calculus.php). But
the interpreter only supports one-letter variable names so you have to
enter the expression:

```
(λc.(λt.(λe.c t e))) (λx.(λy.y)) (λx.(λy.y)) (λx.(λy.x))
```